# query Canvas URL using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

It seems like `http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/application/` provides all the information except for `Canvas URL`. Is it possible to query this information any other way?

Comment: It was available using the old REST api, but I cannot find it on Graph or FQL. `http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appproperties/`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, the solution I came up with, was simply calling the old `admin.getAppProperties` method.

```
$info = $facebook->api(array(
    'method'        => 'admin.getAppProperties',
    'properties'    => array('publish_url'),
));
```